# How to get rid of an image upon collision detection in SDL?

Tags: collision-detection, sdl, c, sdl2

I am fairly new to SDL in C, but I have written a simple game whereby a character has to reach the end of a level and avoid bad stars on the way. If he hits a star, he dies. There are also good stars he can collect and get points.

I have set up my point system so now when he hits a good star, he should get a point. However, when he hits a star, he actually gets lots of points, as long as he is touching the star, which I don't want. I think that what's happening is because the stars are moving and he rubs up against the stars; each pixel he moves counts as a new collision so he gets a point per collision. Ideally, he should only get one point per star.

So I have two problems: 1) I need to figure out how to make it so that he can only get one point when he hits a star. 2) Since he is supposed to be 'collecting' the stars, I want to make the star disappear when he collects it.

So it's similar to most of these types of games, whereby, the player collects something, it disappears and they get a point.

EDIT:

This is struct I've made:

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y, w, h, baseX, baseY, mode;
    float phase;
} Goodstar;
```

I've then referenced it in another struct like so:

```
Goodstar goodStars[GOOD_STARS];
SDL_Texture *goodStar;
```

`[GOOD_STARS]` is equal to 100.

And then here's my collision detection code:

```
// Check for collision with good stars
for (int i = 0; i < GOOD_STARS; i++) {
    if (collide2d(game->man.x, game->man.y, game->goodStars[i].x, game->goodStars[i].y, 48, 48, 32, 32)) {
        if (!game->man.isDead) {
            game->man.points++;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

So right now it only checks for a collision and then adds a point.

EDIT 2:

This is the code you suggested and it works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GOOD_STARS; i++) {
    if (!game->goodStars[i].awarded) {
        if (collide2d(game->man.x, game->man.y, game->goodStars[i].x, game->goodStars[i].y, 48, 48, 32, 32)) {
            if (!game->man.isDead) {
                game->man.points++;
                game->goodStars[i].awarded = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my initialisation code:

```
  // Initialise stars
  for (int i = 0; i < GOOD_STARS; i++) {
    game->goodStars[i].baseX = 320 + random() % 38400;
    game->goodStars[i].baseY = random() % 480;
    game->goodStars[i].mode = random() % 2;
    game->goodStars[i].phase = 2 * 3.14 * (random() % 360) / 360.0f;
        game->goodStars[i].awarded = 0;
  }
```

Comment: How do you store the stars in your game code?

Comment: I've made an array of surfaces and textures of the stars. I load the image of the star and create a surface from it, which I then use to make a texture.

Comment: And how do you check for the collisions?  How do you store the positions of the stars?

Comment: I use a function which checks if the x co-ordinates of any side of the man are equal to the x co-ordinates of a star. And I do the same for y co-ordinates.

Comment: I use co-ordinates of the game window and I initialise the stars this way. Then I use SDL_RenderCopy and SDL_RenderPresent to draw the stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the general approach is the following: you check if the player collides with a star, and if it does, you award the player a point, and then destroy the star.

All right, so seeing your code, I would simply add a boolean called `awarded` or something similar to the `Goodstar`. Initialize that to `false` when you create your stars.

Now, when the player collides with a star, mark `awarded` as `true`, and in the future, don't award points to players if `awarded` is true. So something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < GOOD_STARS; i++) {
    if (!game->goodStars[i]->awarded)
    {
        if (collide2d(game->man.x, game->man.y, game->goodStars[i].x, game->goodStars[i].y, 48, 48, 32, 32)) {
            if (!game->man.isDead) {
                game->man.points++;
                game->goodStars[i]->awarded = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You would also then not render stars that have `awarded` set to true.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm aiming for. I'll post my code in my question.

Comment: So? This is what you already have? What's the issue then? You want me to debug your current code?

Comment: I haven't actually got the `free(star)` code because that's what I didn't know about.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to fit your existing code. Please in the future include it in the question if it plays a significant role in answering.

Comment: But now I'm going to add that in.

Comment: You don't need to do that because you don't use pointers.

Comment: Ok I'll keep that in mind, thank you for your help.

Comment: I've used the pointer because I was writing this game from an online tutorial and that's how the guy in the video did it. But you're right, I'm not sure the pointer's necessary.

Comment: See my edit, I think the boolean approach fits your design better.

Comment: You're right, I think it does, I'm currently trying it out in my code, and just sorting out some errors. But I'll tell you if it worked.

Comment: Ok right now, it mostly works. When he collects a star, the point only goes up by one and you can't get another point from the same star, so that is successful. However, the star doesn't disappear, although I've set `awarded` to false when initialising the stars. My new code is in my question.

Comment: Did you implement the last sentence in my answer? Don't render stars that have `awarded` set to true.

Comment: I just did that now before I read your comment :) I didn't get it first, but then I realised what you meant. I created an if statement, saying if awarded is false, then draw the stars. So now it fully works and when he collects a star, it disappears and he gets a point. Thank you so much, that really helped.

Comment: Glad to help and good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, my project is pretty much finished now, this was just the final thing I needed to sort out.